# SQL Server : filter on time element in datetime format

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-like

I am currently struggling with the following:

I have a SQL query which selects a `datetime` column. Next to that I do a convert in order to get the time only.

```
bc.StartTime as startdatetime,
CONVERT(TIME,bc.starttime) as starttime,
```

Output looks like this:

```
startdatetime              starttime
-------------------------------------------
2019-04-14 19:13:53.000    19:13:53.0000000
2019-04-15 00:00:00.000    00:00:00.0000000
```

So far so good, but now, I want to filter out the "00:00:00.0000000" time.

I've tried several things like:

```
AND CONVERT (time, bc.starttime) != '00:00:00.0000000' 
AND bc.starttime NOT LIKE '%00:00:00.000'
```

but none of them is working.

The `starttime` also contains "NULL"'s - which I would like to keep in my results.

Is there anyone who can help me?

**Edit:**

Thanks for your contribution all!

I am having 4 columns; actdatetime, bcstarttime, date and time. 
I will try to explain what I want:

The date and time column are converted columns from the bcstarttime column.

But I want to filter out the "00:00:00" times in my results.
Because this column is an alias, it doesn't want to be declared in my "WHERE" clause.

If I do the following:

```
WHERE bc.StartTime != '00:00:00'
```

Then it also 'destroys' my NULL values (which I want to keep in the result).

It is probably a newbie thing which I am overlooking....

Comment: Can you add an example of your datatable?

Comment: It would help to see your entire query that doesn't work. One possible source of confusion is that you are using [starttime] as both the original column name (which has a date part) and as a column alias for the time-only part. You are also comparing times or datetimes to strings, and it can be safer to explicitly convert so your comparison compares identical types. Otherwise, implicit conversion occurs, and the rules and formats that apply may not be what you expect.

Comment: The debugging value of "none of them is working" is nil. Do you get an error? Rows that you don't want are returned? Rows that you do want are filtered out? The query is still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a slightly different approach?

```
where (convert(date, bc.starttime) <> bc.starttime or
       startdatetime is null
      )
```

That is, there is something besides the date component.

Or you can do this using times:

```
where (convert(time, bc.starttime) <> '00:00:00.0000000' or
       bc.starttime is null
      )
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, 

Thanks for your contribution. I've tried your suggestion. When I use:
WHERE (convert(time,bc.starttime) <> '00:00:00.000') 

It does indeed the trick. But it is also removing my NULLs for the bc.starttime. Is there a way to keep the NULL and remove the 00:00:00.000 ?

Comment: @Rob . . . The `or` is supposed to be doing that.